# NSPredicate Issue - Not finding data

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have a Core Data model like so:

```c
ArticleCache:
- NSString *link
```

And I have some a custom object like so:

```c
Article:
- NSString *linkString //NSString version of link
- NSURL *link
- NSString *title
```

I have an `NSArray` of `Article`s (`articleList` below), and I have a Core Data store with `ArticleCache`s.

I'm trying to retrieve the `ArticleCache`s that have a matching link in my `articleList`:

```c
NSEntityDescription *articleCacheObjectModel = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ArticleCache" inManagedObjectContext:backgroundContext];

// Setup the fetch request  
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];  
[request setEntity:articleCacheObjectModel];

//search will return all items matching the link
NSPredicate *searchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"link in %@", articleList];
[request setPredicate:searchPredicate];

NSError *error = nil;

NSArray *results = [backgroundContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

When I run this, `results` is always empty, despite that I know there are matching `ArticleCaches` in the Core Data store. I know this because if I remove the predicate from the request, I get all the `ArticleCache`s, and I can print out their respective `link`s and compare them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "link" attribute of the "ArticleCache" entity is a string, and in your predicate you try to test if this string is contained in an array of `Article` objects. That will never match.

You can build an array of string URLs first, e.g.

```
NSArray *urlList = [articleList valueForKey:@"linkString"];
```

and then use that in the predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"link in %@", urlList];
```

Comment: Derp. Thanks. For some reason I though the magic NSPredicate would look through my objects. In fact, it *was* comparing against each `Article`'s `title` attribute (for whatever reason).